# ESPN image 300 pixels even though says 90 pixels

Tags: espn

Just wanted to put this inaccuracy out there to fix.

When pulling from the Now API, the **height and width given for some images does not correspond with the actual size of the image**.

Example:

```
"images": [{
            "height": 90,
            "alt": "",
            "width": 90,
            "name": "Cowherd makes picks for Week 10 in the NFL",
            "caption": "Cowherd makes picks for Week 10 in the NFL",
            "credit": "",
            "url": "http://a.espncdn.com/i/espnradio/stations/espn/shows/300/theherd.jpg"
        },
```

The `height` is `90` and the `width` is `90` yet the image is actually 300px (as tipped off by the jpg url).

Seems to be happening with multiple images I've come across, **can you please fix**?

Thanks!

Comment: Can someone from ESPN help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of December 7 ESPN has closed their API to the public.  Sorry to user2727221 who was looking for a response too.  So no update has been made or will be made to API to fix.